# Не записываются в базу умляуты ( ş, ü, ä, ö, ň ....)

Tags: sql-server

При редактировании БД через Sql Managment Studio умляуты вставляются без проблем. Но  стоит редактировать в виде запроса  `UPDATE docsTbl SET prim='ş'` то в  базу ложится буква s. Что делать, подскажите пожалуйста!!!

Comment: "Но стоит редактировать в виде запроса" - а запрос вы в чем редактируете и исполняете, не в студии?

Comment: запрос тоже задал в студии

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ: `UPDATE docsTbl SET prim=N'ş'` - букву N везде ставить нужно.

В [справке](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) говорится, что префикс N запишет текст в Юникоде, а без него - в дефолтной кодовой странице БД:

> Prefix Unicode character string constants with the letter N. Without the N prefix, the string is converted to the default code page of the database. This default code page may not recognize certain characters.

Comment: Добавил ссылку на справку. У вас же MS SQL ?